# How to specify the 'Issued To' and 'Issued By' for a self server certificate in IIS

Tags: iis, certificate

I'm dealing with a legacy project (produced by a third party we no longer have access to). The project came with a self signed (server) certificate that needs to be updated (it expires soon).

Say the software is called 'SoftwareName'.

I can create a certificate easily enough via IIS but when I look at the old certificate, the fields for 'Subject', 'Issuer', and 'Friendly name' in the Certificate Details tab all give 'SoftwareName'.
When viewed in the 'Server Certificates' section on IIS, the 'Name', 'Issued To', and 'Issued By' fields are all, also, 'SoftwareName'.

But when I create a new certificate, these latter fields (Issued To/By) give my pc's domain name. I don't want this, given the format of the previous certificate.

Is there a way to define these fields when creating a certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer this then :).
The solution I found was to use OpenSSL. Via a combination of command line options and editing of the config file (openssl.cnf).

I ran this command to create a certificate (as pem) and key file:

```
req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

then edited the openssl.cnf to ask for a 'commonName' (I also provide the default to reduce typing):

```
commonName          = SoftwareName
commonName_default  = SoftwareName
```

Then, because I needed the certificate as a pfx:

```
pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -name "SoftwareName" -out certificate.pfx
```

This combination created the set of properties I was looking for.